# Django select distinct not returning properly

Tags: django, django-models, model

Hello I am working on a website and have a question why this is returning the way it is?

I want select distinct 'category' from {table}

I tried both with and without Flat = True

```
In [27]: q = EyeMakeUpWaxing.objects.values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()

In [28]: print q.query
SELECT DISTINCT `eye_make_up_waxing`.`category`, `eye_make_up_waxing`.`created_at` FROM `eye_make_up_waxing` ORDER BY `eye_make_up_waxing`.`created_at` ASC

In [29]: print q
[u'EYE_BEAUTIFICATION', u'EYE_BEAUTIFICATION', u'EYE_BEAUTIFICATION', u'MAKE_UP', u'MAKE_UP', u'MAKE_UP', u'MAKE_UP', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON', u'ENHANCER_ADD_ON']
```

If this is not the django syntax for this plz help in getting the correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ordering statement in there causing issues (from default ordering defined in your models / somewhere else).

Clear the ordering via `order_by()`

```
EyeMakeUpWaxing.objects.order_by().values_list('category', flat=True).distinct()
```

The ordering is forcing a SELECT created_at which makes each of those entries distinct.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Thanks that worked.  
    class Meta:
        
        ordering = ['created_at']
I take it this causes the order by..

Comment: @mcddewitt yes, that's it.